# how to land to next page from first page in Google data studio

Tags: google-cloud-platform, looker-studio

I am doing a two page report in google data studio.The two page contains different level information like suppose the first page is for income level information and the 2nd page contains demographic information. Both pages are related. I want to add a filter kind of thing (I don't know how I can do) on the chart if I click on a part(if it is a bar chart and if I click on one bar) of chart it should go to the second page which contains more information about that group from first page. How to do this I have googled a lot on this but could not find anything.

Answer (score 2):

From your description I would suggest that you review the following documentation it describes what needs to be done in order to create links to pages in your report [Create links to pages in your report](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7054323?hl=en)

It is a simple process;

> You can provide links that take viewers to specific pages in a report.
>   Edit your report.
>   In the toolbar on the top of the page, click Text [icon].
>   Enter the text to display, for example, "Page 2."
>   Select the text you just entered, then on the right, click Insert link.
>   Click Paste a link or select a page.
>   Select a page in this report, or choose a dynamic link.

Comment: Thank you so much for the solution but I am not looking for text box link. I need to add the link in the chart not as a text box. If I add a new field using formula hyperlink(link) to the chart. I am able to see the link in the chart as data label but when I click on this it s not going to next page.

Comment: Then what you are looking for is a feature request to be made.. as what you want is not possible this can be done here https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=196095&template=1100266

Comment: Thanks Paddy, Do you know how the formula "hyperlink" work in google data studio? It does not work on charts? I have tried in a table as well but did not work. There is a hyperlink function in excel as well. Does it works in same way or in a different way.

Comment: hi you can check this https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7431836?hl=en ...This explains the hyperlink functionality and also gives examples

Comment: Hi Paddy, thanks. The hyperlink function is working for tables. Not for charts. I have explored tableau as well in tableau there is a action based filter option where we can set the source page destination page and the filter as well. I am looking for very similar like that. But I think data studio does not have that feature. Thank you so much for your time and help. :)  I will update comment If I get anything new.